# EXT JS -Architecture

Tags: javascript, extjs

Can we create Folders inside Store and Model in EXT JS for Separating modules like, If yes, how to make EXT JS understand the re-organised structure

App

-Store

--Module1(Contains Store files for Module1)

--Module2(Contains Store files for Module2)

-Model

--Module1(Contains Model files for Module1)

--Module2(Contains Model files for Module2)

Comment: Of course! Just make sure the class namespaces match the directory structure, ***e.g.*** `Ext.define('MyApp.store.moduleOne.MyStore', { /* ... */ })`

Answer (score 0):

Sure. You are just namespacing the files. When using the complete namespace, ExtJs will look for the class in the corresponding folder.

Default ExtJs will look for views, stores, etc. in the folders `Myapp.store`, `MyApp.view`, etc.

```
...
stores: ['store1', 'store2'],
views: ['view1', 'view2']
...
```

But when your namespace has subfolders you can use

```
...
stores: ['MyApp.store.module1.store1', 'MyApp.store.module1.store2'],
views: ['MyApp.store.module1.view1', 'MyApp.store.module1.view2']
...
```

You could also refer the class using the relative qualifier such as:

```
...
stores: ['module1.store1', 'module1.store2'],
views: ['module1.view1', 'module1.view2']
...
```